# Изменение ширины и сдвиг UINavigationBar

Tags: ipad, objective-c, ios, iphone, ios7

Есть ли способы изменить ширину UINavigationBar? Нашел код (категорию), который меняет ширину бара, но UINavigationBar остается посредине. Не могу найти, как его сдвинуть вправо.

```
- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size {

    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(250, 44);
    return newSize;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прежде всего вопрос а зачем оно вам надо? Перед тем как менять жестко зафиксированные размеры элементов стоит подумать дважды.

Если же абстрагироваться это этого вопроса, то механизм довольно прост - нужно сделать своего наследника от `UINavigationBar`, указать что именно он будет использоваться, а не стандартный бар. Ну а после этого уже можно поиграть с размерами и положением этого наследника. В принципе, у меня получилось передвинуть с помощью переопределения `setCenter:`

```
-(void) setCenter:(CGPoint)center{
    center.x += kOffset;
    [super setCenter:center];
}
```

Но хочу сразу предупредить, поскольку это вмешательство туда куда эппл изначально программистов не пускает, есть шанс огрести геморрой с поддержкой в разных версиях, у меня такое уже было - что-то привязывал к ресайзу какого-то из сабвью (найденного с помощью перебора массивом subviews), а в очередной версии операционки 6.1 это перестало работать т.к. то ли изменили иерархию видов, то ли просто забили и размер вида всегда был большим и просто кропался (уже не помню)

Comment: а еще могут зареджектить за такое )

Comment: само собой. Но пока именно за это лично меня не реджектили, хотя делал не раз подобные хаки: переставлял надпись с картинкой на UIButton чтобы было как на тулбаре, делал картинки на навбаре и тулбаре когда это еще было нельзя делать (причем именно на навбар, а не просто скрыл и поставил картинку как это обычно делали), кнопки по таббару гонял